# Chrome Text Issues?

Tags: html, css

On Mozilla Firefox, everything looks fine and I have no issues, but when I open it up on Google Chrome, the text on the left side of my page do not show and are all over.

The text I am talking about is "Learn To Design" and "Resources" on the left side of the page above the links. I have never encountered this before.

designatease.com

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="midwrap"><a class="headerone">Welcome to Design At Ease</a>
<p class="paragraph1">So, you want to code? Touch up on your skills? Or maybe you want to make a design on Photoshop and you don't know how? Whatever it is, you came to the right place. I designed this site for the simple use of web designers. I have had a great deal of trouble in the past, while learning to design and I always searched for that one page that gave me all the information I needed. So, I set out to make it! That site is called Design At Ease.</p>
<ul id="tagsone"></ul>
</div>
<a class="Resources">Resources</a>
<ul id="sidelinksleft">
<li><a href="quickstart.html">Quick Start</a></li>
<li><a href="tagsmain.html">Tag Helper</a></li>
<li><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
<li><a href="learn.html">Learn</a></li>
<li><a href="sites.html">Useful Sites</a></li>
</ul>
<a class="learntodesign">Learn To Design</a>
<ul id="sidelinkslefttwo">
<li><a href="html.html">HTML</a></li>
<li><a href="css.html">CSS</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript.html">Javascript</a></li>
<li><a href="othercoding.html">Other Coding</a></li>
<li><a href="photoshop.html">Photoshop</a></li>
<li><a href="morelearning.html">More...</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper{
position:relative;
top:-62px;
margin-right:4%;
margin-left:4%;
width:92%;
height:100%;
background:#fafafa;
border-left: 1px #c9c9c9 solid;
border-right: 1px #c9c9c9 solid;
overflow:hidden;
}

#sidelinksleft {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    float:left;
    height:25px;
    position:relative;
    /*removed clear from here*/
    float:left;
    margin-left:-25px;
    top:15px;
}

#sidelinksleft li{
position:relative;
padding-top:3px;
list-style-type: none;
}

#sidelinksleft li a{
color:#000000;
font-size:13px;
font-family: sans-serif;
text-decoration:none;
background-color:#82CFFD;
height:17px;
position:relative;
border:1px solid black;
width:150px;
padding-left:3px;
padding-top:2px;
padding-bottom:2px;
display:block;
margin-bottom:2px;

}

#sidelinksleft li a:hover{
color:#000000;
font-size:13px;
font-family: sans-serif;
text-decoration:none;
background-color:#B0E2FF;
height:17px;
position:relative;
border:1px solid black;
width:150px;
padding-left:3px;
padding-top:2px;
padding-bottom:2px;
display:block;
margin-bottom:2px;

}

#sidelinksleft li a:active{
color:#000000;
font-size:13px;
font-family: sans-serif;
text-decoration:none;
background-color:#82CFFD;
height:17px;
position:relative;
border:1px solid black;
width:150px;
padding-left:3px;
padding-top:2px;
padding-bottom:2px;
display:block;
margin-bottom:2px;

}

.Resources{
color:#000000;;
font-size:16px;
font-family: sans-serif;
position:relative;
margin-left:-156px;
top:10px;
}

#midwrap {
    width:80%;
    height:90%;
border-left:1px solid #c4c4c4;
    top:10px;
    position:relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    float:right; 
clear:right;
margin-right:47px;

}


.learntodesign{
color:#000000;;
font-size:16px;
font-family: sans-serif;
position:relative;
margin-left:-78px;
top:196px;
}

#sidelinkslefttwo {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    float:left;
    height:25px;
    position:relative;
    /*removed clear from here*/
    float:left;
    margin-left:-25px;
    top:145px;

}

#sidelinkslefttwo li{
position:relative;
padding-top:3px;
list-style-type: none;
}

#sidelinkslefttwo li a{
color:#000000;
font-size:13px;
font-family: sans-serif;
text-decoration:none;
background-color:#82CFFD;
height:17px;
position:relative;
border:1px solid black;
width:150px;
padding-left:3px;
padding-top:2px;
padding-bottom:2px;
display:block;
margin-bottom:2px;

}

#sidelinkslefttwo li a:hover{
color:#000000;
font-size:13px;
font-family: sans-serif;
text-decoration:none;
background-color:#B0E2FF;
height:17px;
position:relative;
border:1px solid black;
width:150px;
padding-left:3px;
padding-top:2px;
padding-bottom:2px;
display:block;
margin-bottom:2px;

}

#sidelinkslefttwo li a:active{
color:#000000;
font-size:13px;
font-family: sans-serif;
text-decoration:none;
background-color:#82CFFD;
height:17px;
position:relative;
border:1px solid black;
width:150px;
padding-left:3px;
padding-top:2px;
padding-bottom:2px;
display:block;
margin-bottom:2px;

}

.headerone{
color:#000000;;
font-size:25px;
font-family: sans-serif;
position:relative;
margin-left:15px;
}

.paragraph1{
color:#000000;;
font-size:14px;
font-family: sans-serif;
position:relative;
margin-left:15px;
}


.paragraph1tag{
color:#000000;;
font-size:16px;
font-family: sans-serif;
position:relative;
margin-left:15px;
}
```

Comment: That's a whole load of CSS, with a surprising lot of `position: relative;`, which makes it hard to tell what's even supposed to be where. Could you try simplifying your code sample, and perhaps posting it as a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [pen](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't use quirks mode. Different browsers have different quirks!

But honestly, this doesn't look like a browser-related issue to me. On all browsers, the links to the left disappear from view if you make the browser window too narrow. Although it happens at different widths for different browsers, but that could be to do with the fonts used.

Comment: It is fine in Mozilla though

Comment: Not on my computer! I tested on Firefox 22, Chromium 30, IE 9 and Opera 12 and they all behave the same: resize the window and the links go away if the window is made too narrow. What OS and what browser versions do you have?